# Modelling aggregate root or domain service?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

I want to model a wishlisting feature for my domain.
My invariants are:

1. You can't add product that is already in your wishlist
2. You can't add product that you own.

The second invariant made me wonder - should I model this feature as reconstituted Aggregate (outside of ORM because of $ownedProductIds that be fetched from UserProductRepository):

```php
final class User extends EventSourcedAggregateRoot
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param UserId           $userId
     * @param ObjectCollection $ownedProductIds
     * @param ObjectCollection $wishlistedProductIds
     * @return $this
     */
    public static function reconstituteFrom(
        UserId $userId,
        ObjectCollection $ownedProductIds,
        ObjectCollection $wishlistedProductIds
    )
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->userId = $userId;
        $user->ownedProductIds = $ownedProductIds;
        $user->wishlistedProductIds = $wishlistedProductIds;

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @throws ProductAlreadyPurchased Thrown when trying to add already bought product
     * @throws ProductAlreadyWishlisted Thrown when trying to add already wishlisted product
     */
    public function addProductToWishlist(Product $product)
    {
        $productId = $product->getId();

        if ($this->ownedProductIds->contains($productId)) {
            throw new ProductAlreadyPurchased($this->userId, $productId);
        }

        if ($this->wishlistedProductIds->contains($productId)) {
            throw new ProductAlreadyWishlisted($this->userId, $productId);
        }

        $this->apply(new ProductWishlisted($this->userId, $product));
    }

    // ...
}
```

or rather create a stateless domain service:

```php
final class Wishlist
{
    public function addProductToWishlist(Product $product, UserId $userId)
    {
        $ownedProductids = $this->userProductRepository->findProductsOfUser($userId);
        $wishlistedProductsIds = $this->userWishlistProductIdRepository->findProductsOfUser($userId);

        // business rules as in User class
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? Maybe I don't get it.

Comment: @guillaume31 The fact is that I haven't read the code carefully and misunderstood the concept of owning a product, which is basically which ones you already bought. I thought products had a single owner concept and you couldn't buy your own products. In that case the model could be quite different. However, now I think the behavior is probably fine on `User`, until a better concept is discovered. The stateless service is not a viable solution if contention exists.

Answer (score 0):

As `User` has all the information needed to enforce the invariants, I would leave it there. I typically only create Domain Services when some operation doesn't seem to belong in one entity (`TransferMoney()` method not fitting in `Account` class is the poster child for this).

Note though that your model is currently really simplistic. As it is, it may make sense to name the aggregate `User`, but in a real situation chances are you will make breakthroughs that completely change it.